# Can I have two File Managers installed in Xubuntu 16.04.5 with no confilcts?

Tags: xubuntu, thunar, nemo

I have Thunar 1.6 as my default file manager, can I install Nemo as my second file manager? I have doubts of installing Nemo and get conflicts between each other. If it is possible should I change some settings in Xubuntu to run it smoothly ? Thanks, Vladi

Comment: You have to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Nemo as a second file manager. I use it as a backup to Nautilus on my GNOME desktop. There are no conflicts but some dependencies will be installed automatically when you install Nemo. Thunar will remain your default file manager unless you manually change it.

Comment: @rofiofogus ok, I'll try.